# Using window.onload with dynamic content in WebExtension

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have a web extension that is loading content into the popup based on existing tokens, and I need it to add a click listener to a button that's dynamically added, but I can't seem to get it to add AFTER the button is inserted into the page. It keeps coming up that `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`.

I've tried using `windows.onload` and `DOMContentLoaded` with no luck

Code

```
// Get and display profile
function outputProfile(ACC_TOK) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'https://private-anon-535ecb43fa-trakt.apiary-mock.com/users/settings');
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + ACC_TOK);
    request.setRequestHeader('trakt-api-version', '2');
    request.setRequestHeader('trakt-api-key', APP_KEY);
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            // Get Response and put in array
            var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            document.body.innerHTML = '<section id="traktProfile"><div id="traktAvatar"><img src="' + response.user.images.avatar.full + '" width="100px" height="100px" alt="' + response.user.name + '" /></div><div id="traktUser"><h1><a href="https://trakt.tv/users/' + response.user.ids.slug + '" target="_newtab">' + response.user.name + '</a></h1><p><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> ' + response.user.location + '</p></div></section><section id="traktSignOut"><a id="traktSignOutLink" class="profileLink">Sign Out</a></section>';
        }
    };
    request.send();
}
// Check if Access Token Exists
chrome.storage.local.get("access_token", function (result) {
    if (result.access_token && typeof result.access_token !== undefined) {
        // Output Profile Page
        outputProfile(result.access_token);
        // Sign out button
        window.onload = function() {
            console.log("DOM Loaded");
            document.getElementById("traktSignOutLink").addEventListener("click", traktSignOut);
        };
    } else {
        // Output Authenctication Page
        outputAuth();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

parden me if i get the wrong idea

why don't you add click here

```
document.body.innerHTML = '<section id="traktProfile"><div id="traktAvatar"><img src="' + response.user.images.avatar.full + '" width="100px" height="100px" alt="' + response.user.name + '" /></div><div id="traktUser"><h1><a href="https://trakt.tv/users/' + response.user.ids.slug + '" target="_newtab">' + response.user.name + '</a></h1><p><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> ' + response.user.location + '</p></div></section><section id="traktSignOut"><a id="traktSignOutLink" class="profileLink" onclick="traktSignOut();">Sign Out</a></section>';
```

Comment: You can't use inline JavaScript with Web extensions :-(

Comment: ya may be I don't know. but at least what i understood by the code above shpuld place the click code in  `this.readyState === 4`. Because onload may call way prior to adding the content to body in the above line.

Comment: Yea tried that as well but then it never loads for some reason

Answer (score 0):

I ended up linking it to another page and running the script from there

Popup.js

```
// Get and display profile
function outputProfile(ACC_TOK) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'https://private-anon-535ecb43fa-trakt.apiary-mock.com/users/settings');
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + ACC_TOK);
    request.setRequestHeader('trakt-api-version', '2');
    request.setRequestHeader('trakt-api-key', APP_KEY);
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            // Get Response and put in array
            var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            document.body.innerHTML = '<section id="traktProfile"><div id="traktAvatar"><img src="' + response.user.images.avatar.full + '" width="100px" height="100px" alt="' + response.user.name + '" /></div><div id="traktUser"><h1><a href="https://trakt.tv/users/' + response.user.ids.slug + '" target="_newtab">' + response.user.name + '</a></h1><p><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> ' + response.user.location + '</p></div></section><section id="traktSignOut"><a href="signout.html" class="profileLink">Sign Out</a></section>';
        }
    };
    request.send();
}
// Check if Access Token Exists
chrome.storage.local.get("access_token", function (result) {
    if (result.access_token && typeof result.access_token !== undefined) {
        // Output Profile Page
        outputProfile(result.access_token);
    } else {
        // Output Authenctication Page
        outputAuth();
    }
});
```

Signout.js

```
window.onload = function () {
    // Get Access Token to clear
    chrome.storage.local.get("access_token", function (result) {
        // Revoke Token
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('POST', 'https://private-anon-535ecb43fa-trakt.apiary-mock.com/oauth/revoke');
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + result.access_token);
        request.setRequestHeader('trakt-api-version', '2');
        request.setRequestHeader('trakt-api-key', APP_KEY);
        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState === 4) {
                if (this.status === 200) {                    
                    // Clear Storage
                    chrome.storage.local.clear(function() {
                        // Alert user
                        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"type": "notification", "title": "Trakt for IMDb Signed Out", "content": "You have been logged out of Trakt for IMDb."});
                        // Redirect back to popup.html
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            window.location.replace("index.html");
                        }, 800);
                    });
                } else {
                     // Alert user
                    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"type": "notification", "title": "Trakt for IMDb Sign Out Error", "content": "Sorry there was an issue signing you out of Trakt for IMDb. Please try again."});
                    // Redirect back to popup.html
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        window.location.replace("index.html");
                    }, 800);
                }
            }
        };
        var body = {'access_token': result.access_token};
        request.send(JSON.stringify(body));
    });
};
```

This may be messy, but it does the trick for me. If anyone works out an easier/better answer I'm all ears :D